# R - ggplot - labs(subtitle=... and caption=...) not working

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I have a problem with properly adding text elements to a plot in some of my charts. I use ggplot2 and + labs(...) but only some elements are included in my plot.

This is one of the charts:

```
colnames(dane.trust)[1] = "Country" #GEO.INDIC_WB
w5 <- ggplot(dane.trust, aes(x = reorder(Country, Trust.Index), y = Trust.Index, fill=Country)) + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2")
w5 + geom_bar(stat="identity") + #guides(fill=FALSE)  +
geom_text(data=dane.trust[,c(1,6)], label = round(Trust.Index, digits = 2),vjust = -0.5, aes(inherit.aes = TRUE, fontface=2)) +
theme_bw() + labs(x="", y="Average Rating (0-10)", title = "Overall trust levels", subtitle="Index of trust to political and legal systems, police and others") +
theme(title = element_text(face = "bold", color = "black"), axis.title = element_text(face = "bold", color = "black"), panel.grid.major.x = element_blank())
```

Title, x.label and y.label are working fine, but i don't see neither the subtitle nor the caption.

There is no error, just those elements are not present.

Does anyone know what may be the problem?

EDIT1:
Here is the output of > dput(dane.trust)

```
structure(list(Country = structure(1:5, .Label = c("Bulgaria", 
"Hungary", "Poland", "Romania", "Slovakia"), class = "factor"), 
Trust.in.the.political.system = c(2.6, 4.5, 3.5, 4.8, 3.5
), Trust.in.the.police = c(3.6, 5.7, 5.2, 6.4, 4.4), Trust.in.others = c(4.2, 
5.3, 6, 6.4, 5.8), Trust.in.the.legal.system = c(3, 5.1, 
4.2, 5.8, 3.6), Trust.Index = c(3.35, 5.15, 4.725, 5.85, 
4.325)), .Names = c("Country", "Trust.in.the.political.system", 
"Trust.in.the.police", "Trust.in.others", "Trust.in.the.legal.system", 
"Trust.Index"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

EDIT2:
I've just checked my original code on other computer, it worked. What could cause that?

Ok, after the reinstall of R and RStudio all worked, thanks all for the answers everybody :).

Comment: This is not a reproducible example. It would help if you could provide the output of `dput(dane.trust)` in a code block.

Comment: Which version of `ggplot2` are you running?

Comment: @JdeMello the version is: ggplot 2_2.1.0

Comment: @Slynny replace the `geom_text(...)` with `geom_text(vjust = -0.5, aes(fontface=2), label = dane.trust$Trust.Index)`. The argument `label` in `geom_text()` can only evaluate `Trust.Index` inside the `aes()` argument. You need to specify the vector in the `label = ...` argument outside `aes()`. Thus you can either do `geom_text(label = dane.trust$Trust.Index, ...)` or `geom_text(data = dane.trust[, c(1, 6)], ..., aes(label = Trust.Index))`.

Comment: looks like you have some good answers, you could accept one of them!

Answer (score 1):

Your error occurs within the incorrect call to `geom_text()` fixit that, everything else shows up just fine.

```r
library(ggplot2)

dane.trust <- structure(list(Country = structure(1:5, .Label = c("Bulgaria", 
                                                                 "Hungary", "Poland", "Romania", "Slovakia"), class = "factor"), 
                             Trust.in.the.political.system = c(2.6, 4.5, 3.5, 4.8, 3.5
                             ), Trust.in.the.police = c(3.6, 5.7, 5.2, 6.4, 4.4), Trust.in.others = c(4.2, 
                                                                                                      5.3, 6, 6.4, 5.8), Trust.in.the.legal.system = c(3, 5.1, 
                                                                                                                                                       4.2, 5.8, 3.6), Trust.Index = c(3.35, 5.15, 4.725, 5.85, 
                                                                                                                                                                                       4.325)), .Names = c("Country", "Trust.in.the.political.system", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                           "Trust.in.the.police", "Trust.in.others", "Trust.in.the.legal.system", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                           "Trust.Index"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

colnames(dane.trust)[1] = "Country" #GEO.INDIC_WB

w5 <- ggplot(dane.trust, aes(x = reorder(Country, Trust.Index), y = Trust.Index, fill=Country)) + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2")

w5 + geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(Trust.Index, digits = 2)), vjust = -0.5) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(
    x = "",
    y = "Average Rating (0-10)",
    title = "Overall trust levels",
    subtitle = "Index of trust to political and legal systems, police and others"
  ) +
  theme(
    title = element_text(face = "bold", color = "black"),
    axis.title = element_text(face = "bold", color = "black"),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank()
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-11-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Unfortunately this code does not work for me either, it gives exactly the same result as before.

Comment: I've just checked my original code on other computer, it worked. Do you have any idea what may be the problem in my PC?

Comment: It's not your pc. Sometimes fresh installs and new sessions fix underlying issues lingering in your environment

Comment: Yep, i decided to reinstall RStudio and R and it worked. So much time lost though. Anyways, thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do

```
w5 <- ggplot(dane.trust, aes(x = reorder(Country, Trust.Index), y = Trust.Index, fill=Country)) + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2")
w5 + geom_bar(stat="identity") + #guides(fill=FALSE)  +
  geom_text(vjust = -0.5, aes(fontface=2), label = dane.trust$Trust.Index) +
  theme_bw() + labs(x="", y="Average Rating (0-10)", title = "Overall trust levels", subtitle="Index of trust to political and legal systems, police and others") +
  theme(title = element_text(face = "bold", color = "black"), axis.title = element_text(face = "bold", color = "black"), panel.grid.major.x = element_blank())
```

The argument `label` in `geom_text()` can only evaluate Trust.Index inside `aes()` when `data` is provided. You either specify the vector in `label = ...` outside `aes()` or insert `label =...` inside `aes()` like so `geom_text(data = dane.trust[, c(1, 6)], ..., aes(label = Trust.Index))`

Comment: No, no, I do not have a problem with value labels. The problem is that of all the things in the line `labs(x="", y="Average Rating (0-10)", title = "Overall trust levels", subtitle="Index of trust to political and legal systems, police and others")` only some are visible. Here the `subtitle="Index of trust to political and legal systems, police and others` part is not shown on the output plot.

Comment: my code produced the same graph as the other answer. When I tried to run your code, I could not produce the graph because of the issue in `geom_text()`, hence my answer. I'd suggest to uninstall `ggplot2` and install it again.